# LINQ include a subset of a query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity in **EF Core** that is using the structure like:

**Course** has an entity **CourseUserRoles** which has the **CourseId**, **UserId** and **RoleId**.

**CourseViewModel** has the same structure as **Course**, except **CourseUserRoles**, instead it has two booleans **IsAdministrator** and **IsContributor**, that are related to the **RoleId**.

I am trying to make a query that won't bring all **CourseUserRoles** for every course queried, but only the ones specific for that user.

I saw that syntactically the below is correct:

```
query =  query.Include(x => x.CourseUserRoles.Where(y => y.UserId == userId));
```

where the query is trying to return a list of courses, I just want to include the ones that have the same Id as the user.
The problem is that the above is throwing an exception.

**Is it possible to only include the CourseUserRoles when the course has the UserId? If it doesn't have it would return null or empty list.**

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass queries in include method. However there is an extension library(EntityFrameworkplus), which adds this feature https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter

Comment: if your datamodel is representing this relation, meaning your user has a Collection of Roles and/or cases, you don't need a query at all. This would be the default behaviour to only load the courses of one user, in the moment when you access the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this by creating separate queries and concatenating as follows:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.CourseUserRoles.UserId != userId)
var queryWithInclude = query.Where(x => x.CourseUserRoles.UserId == userId)
    .Include(x => x.CourseUserRoles)
var fullDataset = query.Concat(queryWithInclude);
```

This keeps both query objects as type IQueryable and not IEnumerable, allowing execution to happen in SQL/server-side rather than in memory.